# unable to load Glide with uri

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-imageview, android-glide

I am working on an App, where, I am listening to image share requests.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="image/*"/>
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="image/*"/>
</intent-filter>
```

I am able to get the Uri(s) of the images shared.

```
private ArrayList<Uri> mGalleryImagesList;

if(recievedAction == Intent.ACTION_SEND){  
    mSelectedImages.add(Uri.parse(extras.get(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM).toString()));
}
else if(recievedAction == Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE){
    ArrayList<Parcelable> fileList = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);

    for (Parcelable file: fileList) {
        mSelectedImages.add(Uri.parse(file.toString()));
    }
}
```

However, when I am trying to load ImageView, using Glide, it is not loading, I am seeing only the place holder.

```
...

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    Glide.with (mContext)
            .load(mGalleryImagesList.get(position))
            .centerCrop()
            .placeholder(R.drawable.image_loading)
            .crossFade()
            .into(holder.imgAlbum);
}
```

Example of Uri that I got when I shared a photo using "Photos" app to my App.
    **content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Ffile%2F3924/ORIGINAL/NONE/1472614544**

No exceptions, only issue is that, ImageView is not loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Image may be too large try to resize it.

```
Glide.with (mContext)
        .load(mGalleryImagesList.get(position))
        .centerCrop()
        .placeholder(R.drawable.image_loading)
        .resize(holder.imgAlbum.getLayoutParams().width, holder.imgAlbum.getLayoutParams().height)
        .crossFade()
        .into(holder.imgAlbum);
```